# how to change `difftime` to numeric

Tags: r

I have some variable that looks like this:

[image]

when I try to plot it, I will get error code `discrete value supplied to continuous scale`. So I have to change it to numeric. I have multiple variables that are this type. IS it a way that I covert them all in once to numeric?

Comment: I find it very interesting that the `str` output says `'difftime' chr`. For comparison, on my console, `str(data.frame(a=diff(rep(Sys.time(), 2))))` displays `'difftime' num`. How exactly did you form a `'difftime'` column that registers as `chr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just a class built on top of `numeric`.  We just need `as.numeric` and assign back to the same column

```
df1$ADY <- as.numeric(df1$ADY)
```

If there are more than one column, just check the column `class`, create a logical vector, use that to select the columns, loop over the selected column and convert to numeric, and assign back to the same columns

```
i1 <- sapply(df1, class) == "difftime"
df1[i1] <- lapply(df1[i1], as.numeric)
```

---

As an example

```
> df1 <- data.frame(ADY = difftime(Sys.time() + 5, Sys.time(), units = 'sec'))
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ ADY: 'difftime' num 4.99964213371277
  ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
> df1$ADY <-  as.numeric(df1$ADY)
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ ADY: num 5
```

Comment: Is it a way to change all `difftime` to `numeric`, instead of one by one? or it is a way we can plot `difftime`?

Comment: @Stataq regarding the plot part, it is not clear how you want to plot

Comment: That is a clever way. For plotting, I would like to use `ADY` as x, just simple line plot. however when I use ADY directly, I will get `discrete value supplied to continuous scale.` I converted ADY to `numeric` and then everything is working. But just wondering whether there is a way to use `ADY` directly.

Comment: `sapply(df1, class) == "difftime"` will error if you have any two-class columns (e.g., `c("POSIXt", "POSIXct")`). An alternative: `sapply(df1, inherits, "difftime")`.

Comment: @r2evans That was my second alternative though I didn't updated

Comment: @Stataq I dont' get the same issue as you showed . i.e. `v1 <- as.difftime(seq(5, 50, by = 5), units = "secs");
plot(v1)`